# Run T4 Text Template when click update button or application restart

Tags: c#, json, json.net, t4

In my application, some setting are coming from JSON settings file. The setting file can be updated from within the program and a `.cs` file is created from these updates with using T4 Text Template. So when the JSON file is updated, I want that the T4 Text Template also works and update the `.cs` file. If this is not possible, I would like the T4 Text Template to run and also update the `.cs` file when I restart the program. But I have no idea how to do it. I managed to create `.tt` file and it works perfectly when I save `.tt` file in the Visual Studio.

**Note:** I have googled for 2 days and read all topic in the site. But I did not reach any result.

Answer (score 1):

You can run command-line transform tool. Here’s an example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\TextTemplating\14.0\TextTransform.exe" "C:\src\template.tt"
```

That will use `TextTransform.exe` from VS2015. VS2017 also has TextTransform.exe, even the freeware community edition, it's located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\`

Documentation for the CLI [is available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/generating-files-with-the-texttransform-utility?view=vs-2017).

Comment: My .Net information is unfortunately still limited. I wrote "how to use TextTransform" to Google, but I didn't understand anything again. Can you give an example? Does this TextTransform work alone? Does it work if I put `TextTransform.exe` next to program files?

Comment: @ColinHenricks “Can you give an example?” I did in the answer, it transforms `C:\src\template.tt` “Does this TextTransform work alone?” you can run it outside visual studio. But then if you want to compile the .cs file that it produces, you’ll need more tools like msbuild or csc. “Does it work if I put TextTransform.exe next to program files?” Have no idea. Very likely it’ll work, but read EULA, I’m not sure you’re allowed to redistribute TextTransform.exe with your application.